# How to crack a username and password using assembly code

Tags: assembly, passwords, x86-64, reverse-engineering

Does anyone know how to figure out the username and password by looking at a set of assembly code for a CheckUserPermissionAccess function? Here is the code, from `objdump -drwC` so relocations are visible.

```
0000000000000120 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()>:
120:   55                      push   %rbp
121:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
124:   53                      push   %rbx
125:   48 83 ec 48             sub    $0x48,%rsp
129:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00      mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
132:   48 89 45 e8             mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
136:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
138:   48 8d 45 bb             lea    -0x45(%rbp),%rax
13c:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
13f:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  144   <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x24>   140: R_X86_64_PLT32     std::allocator<char>::allocator()-0x4
144:   48 8d 55 bb             lea    -0x45(%rbp),%rdx
148:   48 8d 45 c0             lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
14c:   48 8d 35 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 153 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x33>   14f: R_X86_64_PC32       .rodata+0xe9
153:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
156:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  15b  <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x3b>   157: R_X86_64_PLT32      std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char>  const&)-0x4
15b:   48 8d 45 bb             lea    -0x45(%rbp),%rax
15f:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
162:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  167  <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x47>   163: R_X86_64_PLT32      std::allocator<char>::~allocator()-0x4
167:   c7 45 bc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x44(%rbp)
16e:   48 8d 35 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 175 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x55>   171: R_X86_64_PC32       .rodata+0xea
175:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 17c <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x5c>   178: R_X86_64_PC32       std::cout-0x4
17c:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  181 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x61>   17d: R_X86_64_PLT32       std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<  <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char,  std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)-0x4
181:   48 8d 35 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 188  <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x68>   184: R_X86_64_PC32        username-0x4
188:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 18f  <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x6f>   18b: R_X86_64_PC32      std::cin-0x4
18f:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  194 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x74>   190: R_X86_64_PLT32     std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>  >&, char*)-0x4
194:   48 8d 35 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 19b  <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x7b>   197: R_X86_64_PC32       .rodata+0x101
19b:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 1a2 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x82>   19e: R_X86_64_PC32      std::cout-0x4
1a2:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1a7 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x87>   1a3: R_X86_64_PLT32     std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)-0x4
1a7:   48 8d 45 c0             lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
1ab:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
1ae:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 1b5 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x95>   1b1: R_X86_64_PC32      std::cin-0x4
1b5:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1ba <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x9a>   1b6: R_X86_64_PLT32     std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)-0x4
1ba:   48 8d 45 c0             lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
1be:   48 8d 35 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 1c5 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0xa5>   1c1: R_X86_64_PC32      .rodata+0x118
1c5:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
1c8:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1cd <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0xad>   1c9: R_X86_64_PLT32     std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const-0x4
1cd:   89 45 bc                mov    %eax,-0x44(%rbp)
1d0:   83 7d bc 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0x44(%rbp)
1d4:   75 07                   jne    1dd <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0xbd>
1d6:   bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
1db:   eb 05                   jmp    1e2 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0xc2>
1dd:   bb 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%ebx
1e2:   48 8d 45 c0             lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
1e6:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
1e9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1ee <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0xce>   1ea: R_X86_64_PLT32     std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()-0x4
1ee:   89 d8                   mov    %ebx,%eax
1f0:   48 8b 4d e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rcx
1f4:   64 48 33 0c 25 28 00 00 00      xor    %fs:0x28,%rcx
1fd:   74 3b                   je     23a <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x11a>
1ff:   eb 34                   jmp    235 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x115>
201:   48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx
204:   48 8d 45 bb             lea    -0x45(%rbp),%rax
208:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
20b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  210 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0xf0>   20c: R_X86_64_PLT32     std::allocator<char>::~allocator()-0x4
210:   48 89 d8                mov    %rbx,%rax
213:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
216:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  21b  <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0xfb>   217: R_X86_64_PLT32     _Unwind_Resume-0x4
21b:   48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx
21e:   48 8d 45 c0             lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
222:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
225:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  22a <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x10a>  226: R_X86_64_PLT32     std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()-0x4
22a:   48 89 d8                mov    %rbx,%rax
22d:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
230:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  235 <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x115>  231: R_X86_64_PLT32     _Unwind_Resume-0x4
235:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  23a <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0x11a>  236: R_X86_64_PLT32     __stack_chk_fail-0x4
23a:   48 83 c4 48             add    $0x48,%rsp
23e:   5b                      pop    %rbx
23f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
240:   c3                      retq
```

I have tried looking at the `cmp` instructions to see what character was being compared, but I noticed that there was only one `cmp`, so the password would only be one character, which doesn't sound right.

How do you figure out username and password from this?

Comment: That disassembly is from a `.o`, without relocation symbols, so we can't see what actual symbol addresses are being reference for data or calls to other functions, just placeholders like `lea 0x0(%rip), %register` and `call next_instruction`.  Probably it's calling a string-compare function somewhere.  Use `objdump -drwC` to see relocations (and optionally `-Mintel` if you'd rather see that than AT&T syntax.)

Comment: I used the objdump -drwC. I'm still figuring out how to read it to figure out the username and password.

Comment: None of the `call` instructions have the relocations. Maybe try with `-R` as well?

Comment: @Jester: Yes they do, e.g. `1c8:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1cd <CheckUserPermissionAccess()+0xad>   1c9: R_X86_64_PLT32     std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const-0x4`.  Maybe you were still looking at the useless version the OP left at the top of their question?  I edited to fix that since I was editing tags anyway.

Comment: Oh, I missed that I had to scroll to the right. I am used to having the relocs on the next line. I see `-w` does that.

Comment: Okay so you can see that the `cmp` is actually comparing the return value from the `string::compare` function which itself takes an argument from `.rodata+0x118` which is where the expected value should be found.